# SQL Server 2014 Express users cannot connect unless they belong to sysadmin server role?

Tags: sql-server, ssms

Our SQL server will not allow users to connect to the server, in SSMS or excel queries, unless they user is part of the sysadmin server role.  We are using mixed mode authentication.  Is there a way around this?  We do not want to give these users sysadmin access because they are able to execute T-SQL queries.  We simply want to allow users to connect and read from the database.

The users has been granted connect on server and the endpoint.  Here is the script used to  create the user.  Is there something that needs to be modified on the SQL server?

```
/*create user*/
EXEC sp_addlogin 'user','P@55w0rd123!','master'
USE master
EXEC sp_grantdbaccess 'user'
EXEC sp_addrolemember'db_datareader','user'

/*grant user connect access*/
GRANT CONNECT TO [user]
GRANT CONNECT ON ENDPOINT::"TSQL Default TCP" TO "user"
```

UPDATE:
It appears that someone has altered the Public Server Role Permissions.  The query below returns that the permission names Administer Bulk Operations, Authenticate Server, Connect any database, control server, view any definition, view any database, and view any server state are all set to DENY.  Is there a script I can run that will restore the public role?  I am not certain which permissions should be set to DENY, from the above, for the Public role.

```
SELECT * FROM sys.server_permissions WHERE grantee_principal_id=2 and STATE ='D'
```

I have already ran the following code below to re-GRANT access to the Public role.

```
GRANT CONNECT ON ENDPOINT::[TSQL DEFAULT TCP] TO PUBLIC AS SA
GRANT CONNECT ON ENDPOINT::[TSQL DEFAULT VIA] TO PUBLIC AS SA
GRANT CONNECT ON ENDPOINT::[TSQL Local Machine] TO PUBLIC AS SA
GRANT CONNECT ON ENDPOINT::[TSQL NAMED PIPES] TO PUBLIC AS SA
```

Comment: You're granting db access to the master database.  You should be doing that in your target database.

Comment: We have tried both databases and the result is the same.  I performed the same thing on the target database. @squillman

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: `sp_addlogin` is deprecated. Use `CREATE LOGIN` and `CREATE USER` instead (and `ALTER ROLE` replaces `sp_addrolemember`). Normally, there is no need to do any sort of `CONNECT` grant because users are part of the `public` role by default, which automatically has permission to connect.

Comment: Note also that, in mixed-mode authentication, you must pay attention to the login mechanism actually used -- you can't log in an SQL account by supplying Windows account credentials, and vice versa, even if the user name and password match. (And when using Windows authentication, you generally don't supply credentials *at all*, as this is automatically handled by the client.)

Comment: Using windows authentication the error is: 18456 severity 14 state 11 Token-based server access validation failed with an infrastructure error @Alejandro